# Js watermark plugin integration into AngularJs directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, watermark

Hello community been stuck on this one for a while...

**Scenario:** 
I'm using AngularJs on a form and I would like to use the watermark jquery plugin

**What I've tried: *Directive Code*** *(assume **myApp** has already been defined, and watermark.js script reference has been added)*

```
myApp.directive('watermark', function(){
    return{
        restrict: 'A', //make this directive an attribute
        link: function(scope, element, attr){
            $(element).watermark(attr.watermark);
        }
    };
});
```

**And then I use the directive like this in the html**

```
<input type="text" data-ng-model="someModel" data-watermark="Required Field"/>
```

Now what's happening is quite strange, the watermark text shows but as the text of the input
and when I focus on the textbox the watermark text does not dissapear instead I just end up adding text on top of that "Required Field" text that's on the input.

JSFiddles are welcome :D

Thanks Guys!

Comment: Ok guys I removed the attr.watermark and replaced it with 'Please enter value' and it worked... So I guess my question now is attr.watermark?

Comment: if you see put a console.log in `attr.watermark` it gives the correct value . see here http://jsfiddle.net/79pDQ/42/

Comment: Yeah i tried that but once you use it inside the watermark('<in here>') it just doesn't work?

Comment: can you prepare a jsFiddle  ?